# Connection error: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:9092 while sending AdminClient request Kafka

Tags: javascript, docker, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I'm running Kafka, Kafka UI and Zookeeper in Docker with docker-compose. I'm trying to create a post request to my api, for it to create kafka topic while writing to DB. Main problem here is, I cannot reach my Broker. My function to create kafka topic is:

```
const addKafkaTopic = async (
    topicName: string, 
    topicIp: string, 
    topicPort: string
    ) => {
    console.log(`ip: ${topicIp} port: ${topicPort} topic ${topicName}`);

    const kafka = new Kafka ({
      clientId: 'myclient',
      brokers: [`${topicIp}:${topicPort}`]
    });

    const admin = kafka.admin();
    await admin.connect();

    admin.createTopics({
      topics: [{
        topic: topicName,
        numPartitions: 1,
        replicationFactor: 1
      }]
    });

    return await admin.disconnect();
  };
```

And my post api is this:

```
router.post('/postkafka', async(req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.topicName;
    const ip = req.body.topicIp;
    const port = req.body.topicPort;
    console.log('add called!');
    try {
      await addKafkaTopic(
        name,
        ip,
        port
        );
      console.log('func worked!');
      await db('kafka_table').insert({name, ip, port});
      res.status(201).json({ message: 'Data has been added to DB.' });
      console.log("insert has been made")
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong while adding data to DB.' });
    }
    

    return res.end();
  });
```

And here is my docker-compose.yaml:

```
kafka-ui:
    container_name: cnt_macro1_kafka-ui
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka0:29092
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER: zookeeper0:2181
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_JMXPORT: 9997
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper0
      - kafka0

  zookeeper0:
    container_name: cnt_macro1_zookeeper0
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - ./zoo/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./zoo/log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

kafka0:
    container_name: cnt_macro1_kafka0
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper0
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9997:9997"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper0:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka0:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      JMX_PORT: 9997
      KAFKA_JMX_OPTS: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=kafka0$
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.1.100
```

I'm sending request to the endpoint "http://localhost:7007/api/kafka/postkafka" with sending topicName, topicIp and topicPort (topicIp and topicPort are broker's ip & port) in JSON from Postman. However, I tried giving "0.0.0.0" (found this one in kafka container's logs), "127.0.0.1", my local IP, Docker's ip as topicIp and gave "9092" or "29092" in every one of them but they whether gave the error "[BrokerPool] Failed to connect to seed broker, trying another broker from the list: Connection timeout" repeatedly, then gave the error in the question's topic, or closed connection.

I'm confused because once I created a topic with giving 0.0.0.0:9092 as an input but now I cannot do anything. How come?

Comment: Look at your UI container's variables... That is the correct address, not 0.0.0.0, which is not a routable address... But your broker isn't changing, so why are you trying to create a brand new connection for every request? There are much better ways to manage Kafka topic creation. Also, what happens when the `db().insert` fails?  Should the topic be removed?

Comment: Got it. I wasn't adding "await" to admin.connect() :) For anyone who gets the same issue.

Comment: Can you clarify? I see await in your code